# jdbc password change in data sources require restart of the server

Tags: jdbc, websphere-6.1

After a password change for database access test connections were failing in the Websphere 6.1 WAS DMGR.
We then changed the password in the jdbc lookup properties and test connection succeded but in the systemout logs we still are getting invalid logon exception. Is it possible that we have to restart the server everytime we do some changes in the data source properties?

Comment: Yes. That is *very* possible. With some application servers you can use JMX or even a web management console to reconfigure your pools. It depends entirely on how you have things setup.

Comment: as Elliot said it all depends on how you have set this up. To properly diagnose this problem we need more information about your setup. Where do you store the configuration? How do you access it? Did you search on Server Fault for this? You might fare better there with this question (but have to include all the information non the less).